# Is there a way to customize the width of the header for the icon as a case property column?

Tags: commcare

I am using the icon as a case property feature in my case list and want to add a label to the icon. When I add a header to the case property, the text is bunched up and does not expand beyond the width of the icon. Is there a way to customize the width of the header for the icon as a case property column?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is not. Icon columns are set to a fixed percentage of the total screen width.